# Start Activity via Floating Action Button

Tags: android

Can please someone Tell me how to open a new activity  by clicking on the floating action Button? I have tried some things I found on the Internet but that did not work... :/

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you tried and what problems you encountered.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry I thought the description was exact enough. But as my problem already got solved I will be more percise at my next question :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Comment: Trank you that worked for me:)

Answer (score 1):

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View view){ 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```